# Pi Output In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am trying to build a degrees/radians calculator. Here are the functions I have.

```
func degreesToRadians(degrees: Double) -> Double {

    return degrees * (M_PI / 180)

}

func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double {

    return radians * (180 / M_PI)

}

degreesToRadians(90)

radiansToDegrees(M_PI/4)
```

degreesToRadians(90) returns 1.5707963267949
radiansToDegrees(M_PI/4) returns 45.0

What I want to happen is in the Degrees to Radians function instead of 1.5707963267949 I want the output to be π/2. Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: `degreesToRadians` return double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent `90` degrees as `π/2`, what you want to do is

- consider the fraction of `degrees` over 180 (i.e. numerator of `degrees` and denominator of `180`);
- reduce this fraction (i.e. divide both the numerator and denominator by the [greatest common factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)); in the case of `90/180`, the greatest common factor is, in fact, `90`, yielding a reduced numerator of `1` and a reduced denominator of `2`;
- the result as a string representation of the fraction, i.e. something like

  ```
  "\(reducedNumerator)π/\(reducedDenominator)"
  ```

  Obviously, if either the numerator or denominator are `1`, then you can suppress that portion of the string, but hopefully you get the basic idea.

Take a crack at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly: "π/2", I don't think this is possible with double. You might get this in String, but not in a number. I think your best option would be to take an optional bool in which case result is returned as multiple of pi.

```
degreesToRadians(90, resultAsMultipleOfPi:true)
```

If this bool is true then 0.5 should be returned. You may need to do some rounding off to get well rounded numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely on what is really `M_PI` you will see that it is predefined double value in math.h that equals

```
#define M_PI        3.14159265358979323846264338327950288   /* pi             */
```

If you want more precision you can declare and use long double value instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use M_PI constant.

If you need in float format just use this,

```
let pi = Float(M_PI)
```